# Get variables from summary?

Tags: r, linear-regression, summary

I want to grab the Standard Error column when I do summary on a linear regression model. The output is below:

```
         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -8.436954   0.616937 -13.676  < 2e-16 ***
x1          -0.138902   0.024247  -5.729 1.01e-08 ***
x2           0.005978   0.009142   0.654  0.51316    `
...
```

I just want the Std. Error column values stored into a vector. How would I go about doing so? I tried model$coefficients[,2] but that keeps giving me extra values. If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: What type of object do you have?

Comment: For lm model: coef(summary(model))[,2]

Answer (score 1):

Say `fit` is the linear model, then `summary(fit)$coefficients[,2]` has the standard errors. Type `?summary.lm`.

```
fit <- lm(y~x, myData)
summary(fit)$coefficients[,1]   # the coefficients
summary(fit)$coefficients[,2]   # the std. error in the coefficients
summary(fit)$coefficients[,3]   # the t-values
summary(fit)$coefficients[,4]   # the p-values
```

Comment: It's slightly preferable to use `coefficients(summary(fit))` rather than `summary(fit)$coefficients`.  You shouldn't need to understand the internal structure of the `summary.lm` object in order to get the coefficients.